# How can I configure an iMac running Ubuntu as a second display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, mac

I was gifted an older iMac that I have setup as a home server running Ubuntu Server 17.10. I'd like to make use of the large display as a second display for my laptop that is running 16.04 LTS. According to the Apple website, the 27" model that I have is capable of displaying input from an external source via its DisplayPort connector with the Apple OS installed. The graphics card is a Radeon 4850.

I have an HDMI to DisplayPort converter ready to use, but I'm unsure of how to configure the machine to accept the external signal.

Comment: Maybe this question on StackOverflow might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491594/reverse-engineering-the-target-display-mode-on-an-imac

Comment: @Danibix Thanks! That was exactly what I needed.